# Branching the product of binary and continuous variable in Gurobi

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, gurobi, nonlinear-programming, binary-variable, branch-and-bound

I have a binary variable (X) multiplying a continuous variable (Y). I know I can linearize by adding an auxiliary variable (I have that model working), but I now want to do my own branching in the binary variable.

For what I read on Gurobi's documentation, I guess that it should be done by tightening the domain of variable X until getting to the binary solution. But I have no idea how to implement this, or even if it makes sense.

I saw this video of Gurobi, but I think is more complex that what I need for my binary variable. And I end up more confused than before.

I hope someone could guide me in how to do a branching on a binary variable in Gurobi (I use python, but can extrapolate from the other languages).

Comment: There are some attributes/params that can queries and set like VarBranch, BranchPrior, BranchDir and IntegralTOI. You can check these posts: https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360078268432-Customized-branching-rule. https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360078268432-Customized-branching-rule. https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/integralityfocus.html